# How to display login error message at login.jsp page using Spring Security?

Tags: java, jsp, error-handling, spring-security

I am using Spring Security. I want to display login error message on `login.jsp` such as login failed or account locked. How can I display such message on login page ?

Comment: @Jigar: yes , i m using spring security. In my application authentication is done through ldap. i want to display login fail, account locked message from message.properties file. for this  i have write down `AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent`, so in this event i m incrementing counter in database. after incrementing counter i want read error message from properties files and display this message on login page. how can i display such message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just configure `authentication-failure-url` to a `Servlet` and set an attribute from that servlet like

```
request.setAttribute("errorMessage",putYourMessageHere);
```

and forward this request to login page.

Or provide

`authentication-failure-url` as `login.jsp?authValid=false`

check for the param on jsp

```
${param.authFailed}
```

and print the message conditionally